# How do I convert a integer representing a character to a string?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am reading a file in Java, which gives me each character as an integer, and then processing each character one at a time. However, I cannot compare that character when it is in integer form, so how can I convert it?

Example:

I want: `93` → `A`

**NOT:** `5` → `5`

Then, I can compare it with an "if" statement.

Comment: Why can't you compare the characters too other characters?  why does it need to be a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Character.toString((char)93);
```

Use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) if you are starting with a string containing the characters `9` and `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work"

```
int i = 93;

char c = (char)i;
```

Basically you typecast the int to its equivalent character.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast like int i = read(); char aChar = (char)i; when appending stringBuilder.append((char)i); or string += (char)i;